# I have a container view inside of view and the container view is connected to a view through a segue.How to access the elements of the main view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a container view inside of view and the container view is connected to a view through a segue.How to access the elements of the main view.[Here as you can see the Tag Container View inside the ProductDetailsViewController contains PrintTagViewController][1].My objective is to access elements of the ProductDetailsViewController from PrintTagViewController for e.g. when I click on a button present in PrintTagViewController ; the stepper inside ProductDetailsViewController should get incremented.

Comment: Could you share `prepareForSegue ` and `PrintTagViewController` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `Protocol` for `PrintTagViewController` and declare `ProductDetailsViewController` as the `delegate` of PrintTagViewController.

There are plenty of resources online for Swift delegates and protocols, here are two examples:

- https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/
- https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html